# Common Lisp vs. MacLisp/InterLisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there a good source document/site with comprehensive comparison of the differences between Common Lisp and MacLisp/Interlisp?

I'm particularly interested in the detailed description of the differences in Property List, and if any, Common Lisp implementation of some of the built-in functions/macros in MacLisp/Interlisp that doesn't exist in Common Lisp.

**Edit** OK, maybe a little bit of context about my question. I was asked to 'translate' a Lisp tutorial which looked like it was based on MacLisp/Interlisp into one based on Common Lisp. I'm pretty new at Lisp and this project is meant to help me learn it. Hence, I was scrambling around to look for resources to help with the 'translation'. So I turn to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm just curious if someone had done so. I've seen bits and pieces of information scattered in different sites/documents.

Comment: Apparently they're not one and the same: [clisp.org](http://www.clisp.org/summary.html). CLISP is an implementation of Common Lisp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kent Pitman's online MacLisp manual has a pretty detailed section on [converting MacLisp/Zetalisp to Common Lisp](http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/cl-conv-01-intr.html), with some discussion of property lists in [Section 3: Easy Changes](http://maclisp.info/pitmanual/cl-conv-03-easy.html).

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, Common Lisp has lexical scoping, which MACLisp and InterLisp didn't have.

Comment: Interlisp and MacLisp use CL's rules in the compiler, but in the interpreter, all variables are dynamically scoped.